# The checkbox doesn't update the bool property from false to true in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The `ViewModel` has the following code:

```
public List<MarketingCode> MarketingCodes { get; set; }
```

Where `MarketingCode` is of type:

```
public class MarketingCode
{

    public bool selected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public MarketingOptionCode name { get; set; }
    public string Line { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    [Flags]//Indicates that an enumeration can be treated as a bit field; i.e., as a set of flags
    public enum MarketingOptionCode
    {

        Email = 1,

        Post = 2,

        SMS = 3,

        Telephone = 4
    }

}
```

My view has following code to render `CheckBoxList`:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MarketingCodes.Count(); i++)
                                    {
                                        var name = @Model.MarketingCodes[i].name.ToString();
                                        <label for="@Model.MarketingCodes[i].name" class="checkbox inlineblock">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MarketingCodes[i].selected, new { name = @Model.MarketingCodes[i].name.ToString(), @id = @Model.MarketingCodes[i].name.ToString() }) **@* This works totally fine, even if you click the label, the checkbox will be checked. *@**

                                            @Model.MarketingCodes[i].name
                                        </label>
                                    }
```

As you can see the `CheckBoxes` are bind with the selected property but it doesn't get update to true when `CheckBox` is clicked! The same approach works fine if there is only a single `CheckBox`. But as such I am using a loop it is not working when I read the value of the property `MarketingCodes` in my controller, all the selected property is false.

The controller code where I am fetching the values from UI:

I have written this private function to call when the index get method fires and also when the post method fires ***because the `viewmodel` was not holding any values when the form was posted. And I guess this is the point where all the selected property is set to false.***

```
 private static void BindMarketingOptions(PersonalDetailsIndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.MarketingCodes = new[] { 

            new Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode { name = Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode.MarketingOptionCode.Email, Line= "line1", value="value1" },
            new Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode { name = Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode.MarketingOptionCode.Post, Line= "line2", value="value2"  },
                new Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode { name = Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode.MarketingOptionCode.SMS,Line= "line3", value="value3"  },
                    new Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode { name = Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode.MarketingOptionCode.Telephone, Line= "line4", value="value4"  }
                    }.ToList();
    }
```

**I have changed the above method to the following to make my selected property work:**

```
private static void BindMarketingOptions(PersonalDetailsIndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.MarketingCodes == null)
        {
            viewModel.MarketingCodes = new[] { 

            new Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode { name = Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode.MarketingOptionCode.Email, Line= "line1", value="value1"},
            new Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode { name = Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode.MarketingOptionCode.Post, Line= "line2", value="value2"},
                new Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode { name = AQuoteBike.ViewModels.MarketingCode.MarketingOptionCode.SMS,Line= "line3", value="value3"},
                    new Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode { name = Bike.ViewModels.MarketingCode.MarketingOptionCode.Telephone, Line= "line4", value="value4"}
                    }.ToList();
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.MarketingCodes.Count(); i++)
        {
            viewModel.MarketingCodes[i].selected = viewModel.MarketingCodes[i].selected;
        }


    }
BindMarketingOptions(viewModel);
for (var i = 0; i <= viewModel.MarketingCodes.Count(); i++)
                {
                    UserField userField = new UserField();
                    if (viewModel.MarketingCodes[i].selected)  //<--FALSE FOR ALL THE CHECKBOXES
                    {
                        userField.Line = viewModel.MarketingCodes[i].Line;
                        userField.Type = viewModel.MarketingCodes[i].name.ToString();
                        userField.Value = viewModel.MarketingCodes[i].value;  
                        BikeQuote.BikeRisk.UserFields.Add(userField);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be seen in the question itself. Overriding the name of the checkbox was not an issue, instead I want to override the name so that for attribute of label works with the name of the checkbox. So, if a user clicks the label, the checkbox is clicked. 
The actual problem was the way I was binding the data to the MarketingCodes property. I have given the old version as well as the updated version. And it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the `name` property of each checkbox - which is what the default model binder uses to try bind the data to your model, best let MVC generate that for you e.g.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MarketingCodes.Count(); i++)
{
    ...
    Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MarketingCodes[i].selected);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did mistake while copy pasting my code. I am using the above CheckboxFor and not Checkbox. Please see the code again.

Comment: @Yoda yep you are....but your *still* overriding the `name` property of the control. Replace your `CheckBoxFor` code with mines and your problem should go away.

Comment: I have tried checking your code but while reading the values in controller it still says false. And the reason for giving the name in that way was so as to match the for attribute for label so that if user clicks label the checkbox is clicked. => which doesn't work now. I have also added my controller code now where the selected is false for all the controls.

Comment: I think I have found my mistake. It is the BindMarketingOptions(viewModel) call in POST method which is setting all the line, name, value properties but not the selected property which is then assigned as false by default. I did this as I want to give some data to MarketingCodes on GET but the values were missing on POST. How can I achieve this?